# extending has_one methods in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This may be unconventional but is it possible to extend any has_one methods in the controller such as `association=(associate)`.  I have seen this done in the model but can it be done in the controller if yes, how?

Some explanation on what i'm driving at...

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

```
Overriding generated methods
```

Association methods are generated in a module that is included into the model class, which allows you to easily override with your own methods and call the original generated method with super. For example:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :owner
 belongs_to :old_owner
 def owner=(new_owner)
   self.old_owner = self.owner
   super
  end
end
```

Also,

```
Association extensions
```

The proxy objects that control the access to associations can be extended through anonymous modules. This is especially beneficial for adding new finders, creators, and other factory-type methods that are only used as part of this association.

```
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :people do
       def find_or_create_by_name(name)
         first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
         find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
       end
     end
    end

person = Account.first.people.find_or_create_by_name("David Heinemeier Hansson")
person.first_name # => "David"
person.last_name  # => "Heinemeier Hansson"
```

---

EDIT

I have 3 models involved; a user model, a captain model, which is a self join model with User and a team model. I am trying to create a one to one relationship between the team  model and the captain model, whereby a user can select a captain for the team from the users on that team; below is my models..

Team Model
    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :profiles, through: :users
      has_one :captain, :class_name => "User"
      has_one :result, as: :result_table

```
  attr_accessible :teamname, :color, :result_attributes

  after_create :build_result_table
  after_create :build_default_captain

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :captain
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :result

  def build_result_table
    Result.create(result_table_id: self.id, result_table_type: self.class.name)
  end

  def build_default_captain
    captain.create(team_id: self.id)
  end

end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :teammates, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "captain_id"
  belongs_to :captain, :class_name => "User"

  # before_create :build_profile
  after_create :build_default_profile

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes

  def build_default_profile
    Profile.create(user_id: self.id)
  end
```

end

Team Controller

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @team = Team.new
end 

def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  if @team.save!
   flash[:success] = "Team created."
   redirect_to @team
  else
   flash[:error_messages]
   render 'new'
  end
 end

def index
 @teams = Team.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def show
 @team = Team.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
 @team = Team.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  if @team.update_attributes(params[:team])
   flash[:success] = "Team Updated"
   redirect_to @team
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

def destroy
  Team.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Team is deleted."
  redirect_to teams_url
 end


 private

  def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:teamname, :color)
  end

end
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Controllers don't have `has_one` associations, they are controllers. So what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I am trying to utilize extension capabilities of the has_one association in the model from the controller.

Comment: Can you show your model with the has_one association, and what do yoi want to achieve in your controller?

Comment: @dgilperez, i have added the models involved.